# Unable to fetch returnurl in asp.net mvc Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two controllers Base and Login.

Base Controller:

```
public ActionResult start()
    {
       string action = Request.QueryString[WSFederationConstants.Parameters.Action];
    }
```

Login Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Login(string user,string password,string returnUrl)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(user, password))
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                returnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);

           return RedirectToAction("Start","Base", returnUrl });
        }
        return View();
    }
```

After authentication is done it gets redirected to Start action in Base Controller as expected.
But the querystring doesnot fetch the value. When hovered over the querystring it shows length value but not the uri.

How to use the url sent from Login controller in Base Controller and fetch parameters from it?

Comment: What is `WSFederationConstants.Parameters.Action`. And it needs to be `return RedirectToAction("Start","Base", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });` if the value of that constant is `"returnUrl"` (your getting `length=9` because there are 9 characters in "returnUrl")

Comment: as suggested by @StephenMuecke i did and am able to get the url in Base Controller. But the url fetched is not in proper format it comes with '%2f%f wsignin...' in place of /(slash) and ?(question mark) so action variable is unable to fetch the action from querystring.

Comment: That because the method encodes it. But what is the purpose of this? If you have a value for `returnUrl`, why are you not just redirecting to it using `return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);` - what is your `start()` method for?

Comment: I have many parameters inside the url .Its not just action parameter alone.It has parameter to perform a sign in .

Comment: What difference does that make.

Comment: My start() method does signin and signout process. After authentication it in login controller, it will take to start() of Base controller and issues a token for the session and does single sign on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112863/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kaarthick-raman).

Answer (score 0):

You are actually returning a 302 to the client.
From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx).

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser
>   to make a GET request to the specified action.

When doing that the client will make another request with the url that you created. In your case something like `youruri.org/Base/Start`. Take a look at the network tab in your browser (F12 in Chrome).

What I think you want to do is:

```
return RedirectToAction
  ("Start", "Base", new { WSFederationConstants.Parameters.Action = returnUrl  });
```

Assuming that `WSFederationConstants.Parameters.Action` is a constant. If `WSFederationConstants.Parameters.Action` returns the string `fooUrl` your action will return the following to the browser:

```
Location:/Base/Start?fooUrl=url
Status Code:302 Found
```

Another option is to actually pass the value to the controller:

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult start(string myAction)
    {
       string localAction = myAction; //myAction is automatically populated.
    }
}
```

And in your redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction
  ("Start", "Base", new { myAction = returnUrl  });
```

Then the `BaseController` will automatically fetch the parameter, and you don't need to fetch it from the querystring.

Comment: I have many parameters inside the url . I have to fetch them using querystring and as suggested by stephen i am able to get the url in Base Controller. But the url fetched is not in proper format it comes with '%2f%f wsignin...' in place of /(slash) and ?(question mark) so action variable is unable to fetch the action from querystring.